# DNS Not resolving from time to time

Tags: django, dns, openshift

I have an openshift app (www.stocksonthebeach) written in django.  From time to time, my application will alert that it cannot resolve the DNS name for the host, see below.

When this happens, the site is fine and things come back just fine, I just want to know what's causing this or how I can figure out what to look for?  It happens 1-2 times day at most, others 2-5 / week.

I'm on the bronze plan, scaled application, Postgresql 9.2, python 2.7.

I would like to know what is causing this please.

```
OperationalError: could not translate host name "53c8ad74e0b8cdca58000029-compunique.rhcloud.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a dns outage on our part. Next time this happens go ahead and open a bug here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online.

Comment: Sadly, happened a bunch this AM, it's pretty regular.  I'll open a bug report tonight